# "Assume that the file name is given as command line argument", what is meant by that?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I need to write a shell script for displaying the total number of words, characters, and lines in a file, but the filename is "given as command line argument".  What is meant by that and how do I use this?

Comment: It just means your script is invoked with the file name as the first argument. e.g: `./my_script.sh filename`

Comment: google `parsing command line arguments`

Comment: that's really something that should be found in the same course materials as this assignment

Answer (score 5):

If the filename is given as a command line argument, this means that your script is being invoked as

```
./myscript.sh some-file-name
```

i.e., the filename is given as an argument on the command line.

As a consequence of this, the first element of the script's list of *positional parameters* will automatically be populated with the name of the file.   The positional parameters are the values `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. (there are `$#` of these), and in this case, only `$1` will contain something (the given filename).

To use the given filename in the script, use `"$1"`.  To get a more readable code, assign this to a named shell variable:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Pick out the filename given on the command line.
name=$1

# Verify that the given name is indeed a (regular) file,
# or a symbolic link to a regular file.
if [ ! -f "$name" ]; then
    # It's not, so output error message and exit.
    printf 'The given name "%s" is not a regular file!\n' "$name" >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf 'The given filename is "%s"\n' "$name"
```

The above script additionally verifies that the given filename exists and is a regular file (not e.g. a directory), or a valid symbolic link to a regular file.

---

As a side note:  When writing a script that requires one or several filenames from the user, arranging for the script to take the filename(s) from the command line, as above for example, is preferred.  The alternative, to read the filename(s) interactively or from a file, is awkward for the user who then can't use the shell's filename globbing and/or tab completion facility to give correct filenames. It may also be impossible to type certain filenames interactively.

---

If you just want the *functionality* of counting words, characters, and lines in a text file, then this is already done by the `wc` utility:

```
$ wc .zsh_history
    7824   35317  333801 .zsh_history
```

In the above example, the file `.zsh_history` has 7824 lines, 35317 words, and 333801 characters.

See `man wc` on your system.